# How can I undo an upvote of a comment?

Tags: support

I want to ask just what is in the title: How can I undo an accidental upvote of a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. It has been proposed as a feature request [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) and declined. Comments don't matter that much in the grand scheme of things anyway, so try not to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks @David Zaslavsky, the accident was due to Murphy`s law ... LOL